# HTML/CSS: Auto scoll issue when hover over a partially displayed element

Tags: html, css, scroll, hover, html-lists

I have created a couple of blocks with css and html [here](http://test.uoncyber.com/error/). It reveals some additional texts when hovering over the block.
My issues is that the first block in each row automatically scrolls on hover when it is partially displayed.

How can I fix this?

I forgot to say that I'm testing this on google chrome Version 66.0

Here is the css and html coding

```css
ul.category-blocks {
        display:block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        list-style:none;
        width:calc(33% - 10px);
        padding:0 0 calc(33% - 10px) 0;
        margin:0 5px 10px 5px;
        float:left;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        background-color:orange;
        background-position:center;
        background-size:100% 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px solid #ff5601;
        transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li:hover {
        background-size:105% 105%;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li > div {
        position:absolute;
        background:rgba(249,91,0,0.7);
        color:#fff;
        left:0;right:0;
        bottom:0;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li:hover > div {
        transition:background 1s ease-in-out;
        background:rgba(249,91,0,0.9);
    }
ul.category-blocks > li > div > h2 {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:700;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li > div > p {
        margin:0;
        padding:0 10px;
        max-height:0;
        font-size:12px;
        text-align:justify;
        transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li:hover > div > p {
        max-height:600px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li > div > p a.shop-button {
        display:block;
        padding:5px 10px;
        margin:10px auto 0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        width:100px;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        color:#fff;
    }
ul.category-blocks > li > div > p a.shop-button:hover {
        background:#fff;
        color:#ff5601;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="category-blocks">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2>Test Title</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: The very first tile seems to have the text fold out downwards, making it push the elements below it further down. Is that what you meant by row automatically scrolling? It seems that it's only the very first tile that has the issue. Every other tile looks fine, even the first tile of every other row. So have you checked to see if every tile has the same css coupled with it?

If you could post some code also, it'd help a lot.

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for your quick response! I have updated the post with the css and html coding. I really appreciate if you can have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```css
       ul.category-blocks {
            display:block;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        ul.category-blocks > li {
            position:relative;
            list-style:none;
            width:calc(33% - 10px);
            padding:0 0 calc(33% - 10px) 0;
            margin:0 5px 10px 5px;
            float:left;
            overflow:hidden;
            border:1px solid #ff5601;
            transition:500ms all;
            background-color:orange;
        }

        ul.category-blocks > li > div {
            position:absolute;
            background:rgba(249,91,0,0.7);
            color:#fff;
            left:0;right:0;
            bottom: 54px;
            transform: translateY(100%);
            -webkit-transform:  translateY(100%);
            -moz-transform:    translateY(100%);
            -ms-transform:      translateY(100%);
            -o-transform:       translateY(100%);
            transition: 500ms all;
        }
        ul.category-blocks > li > div > h2 {
            text-align:center;
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:700;
        }
        ul.category-blocks > li > div > p {
            margin:0;
            padding:0 10px;
            font-size:12px;
            text-align:justify;
            transition:500ms all;
        }

        ul.category-blocks > li:hover > div
        {
            transform: translateY(54px);
            -webkit-transform:   translateY(54px);
            -moz-transform:    translateY(54px);
            -ms-transform:       translateY(54px);
            -o-transform:        translateY(54px);
        }
```

```html
<ul class="category-blocks">
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>
            <h2>Test Title</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis vestibulum arcu. Donec eu tortor ac eros consequat ultricies. Nam luctus leo id ipsum vulputate, et interdum mauris lacinia. Praesent auctor egestas blandit. Sed nisi lectus, blandit non enim et,</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```